# One Mongo instance in JavaEE 6 app

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi

It is said that there should be one `Mongo` instance per JVM. I'm trying to setup `Mongo` in JEE6 app and so far I have it done like this.

```
@Startup
@Singleton // EJB not CDI singleton
public class MongoDatabase {

  private Mongo mongo;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() throws Exception {
    mongo = new Mongo();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    mongo.close();
  }

  @Produces
  public DBCollection getProjectsCollection() {
    return mongo.getDB("testdatabase").getCollection("mycollection");
  }

}
```

This is ok, I can `@Inject` it to all CDI services I want and starts at app startup, but it is not one per JVM, it is one per application. If I have several apps deployed on my app server all of them could setup its own `Mongo` if needed.

How to setup one `Mongo` per server in JEE6 so that all apps deployed can have access to the same connection pool (something similar to datasources to RDBMS)? Can I register it in JNDI somehow? Or maybe it is not needed as per application is enough?

Comment: Does this [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10729249/162228) answer your question?